# Why are my solutions to the Christoffel symbols of polar coordinates recipricoled?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, polar-coordinates, geodesic

I just gave myself some practice with Christoffel symbols, using the polar coordinates formula of $[x, y] = [r\cos\theta,\,r\sin\theta]$. I then calculated the Christoffel symbols, and I got six correct ($\Gamma^r_{\theta\theta}$ was $-r$ and the others were zero) but the two that are giving me trouble are $\Gamma^\theta_{r\theta}$ and $\Gamma^\theta_{\theta r}$, for both of which I got an answer of $r$, when the video I was watching told me it should have been $1/r$. Why is this? The equation I was using for Christoffel symbol $\Gamma^k_{ij}$ was$$\frac{\partial e_i}{\partial x^j}\cdot e^k$$ Which I interpreted to be the dot product of the second derivative of $[r\cos\theta,\,r\sinθ\theta]$ with respect to $i$ and $j$ and the derivative with respect to $k$ (because I am under the impression that basis vectors are derivatives, and you may correct me if I'm wrong). Here is a link to [the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TvFvL_sMg4g) and to [the equation I used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christoffel_symbols). I just can't see how the answer can be $1/r$.

Comment: I've improved your [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020). From the original edit, I'm guessing you'd have trouble editing in the calculations that got you incorrect answers, but I think I know what the problem is. I've preserved your original index heights, but it should actually be$$\Gamma^k_{ij}=\frac{\partial e_i}{\partial x^j}\cdot e^k.$$Note $e_i$ is not the same as $e^i$; it's $g_{il}e^l$. The difference is subtle in Cartesian coordinates, but profound in polar ones. I hope that helps.

Comment: @J.G. Yeah, that is what I meant. Also, now that you mention it, I think maybe my problem was due to me treating e<sup>k</sup> as e<sub>k</sub>. I'll look into subscripts and superscripts.

Comment: Best of luck. In the mean time, $e^{k}$ ($e_{k}$) is written with `e^{k}` (`e_{k}`), although the braces around a single character are optional.

Comment: If you can't find your mistake, feel free to copy the calculations here and we can check them.